# AJAX and user leaving a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a chat and I'm trying to figure out how I can detect that the user has left the page or not. Almost everything is being handled by the database to avoid the front end from messing up.

So what I'm trying to do is once the page is left for any reason (window closed, going to another page, clicking a link, etc.) an ajax call will be fired before a person leaves so I can update the database.

This is what I've tried:

```
$(window).unload(function(){
      $.post("script.php",{key_leave:"289583002"});
});
```

For some odd reason, it wouldn't work, and I've checked the php code, and it works fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript, browsers, window close - send an AJAX request or run a script on window closing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162188/javascript-browsers-window-close-send-an-ajax-request-or-run-a-script-on-win)

Comment: look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945932/window-onbeforeunload-ajax-request-in-chrome/55651530#55651530

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(window).unload(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'script.php',
        async:false,
        data: {key_leave:"289583002"}
    });
});
```

Note the `async:false`, that way the browser waits for the request to finish.

Using `$.post` is asynchronous, so the request may not be quick enough before the browser stops executing the script.

Comment: My goodness it worked! Thank you very much, learned something new today :-)

Comment: The code above works well but as of jQuery 1.8 the .unload() method was [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/unload/) and replaced with ```$(window).on('unload', function() {});```

Comment: This might be OK as far as it goes, but what if the user experiences a power cut, for example. Better would be something that says "I'm still here" (heartbeat) rather than "I'm leaving now".

Comment: Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't the correct way of doing this... Suppose the OS just hangs or something happens in the browsers process then this event wont be fired. And you will never ever know when the user has left, showing him/her online ever after he/she has disconnected. Instead of this, what you can do is.

1. Try connecting a socket so that you can know the user is disconnected when the socket is disconnected
2. You can send a request to the server (say after every 1 sec) so that you can know that the user is still connected. If you didn't receive the request - even after 2 secconds - disconnect the user.

Comment: I don't know how to do that, do you have an example?

Comment: what r u using server side? asp.net ?

Comment: He is using PHP. Here is nice source which can help you get started https://github.com/nicokaiser/php-websocket Also it has  SWF object for socket implementation for browsers which do not support web sockects.

Comment: Surprised this answer was at -1. Just raised it to 0. Maybe it's not as well written as it might be but it makes a very important point and suggests solutions.

Comment: Option number 2 is exactly what I'm trying to do. I know how the ajax should be but do you have any suggestions on how I can do this in Django's side?

Comment: @aaronn - this might help https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 1):

Try to add popup (prompt("leaving so early?")) after $.post. It may work. Tho it may be bad user experience. :)

Comment: I doubt it will work with any variation, many browsers have different policies when browser is closing or just tab is closing or even page url is redirected to other url. Bigest problem here is that when page is "closing" all connections and other stuff is disposed! So even you send POST request few milliseconds before page is disposed there is big chance that connection will be terminated... That is why I suggested you to use prompt after $.post function call. I will try to create sample but I can't promise anything.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the answer above. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10272651/1306144

This will execute the ajax call every 1 sec. (1000)

```
function callEveryOneSec() {
    $jx.ajax({}); // your ajax call
}

setInterval(callEveryOneSec, 1000);
```

Comment: I think sending AJAX every one second can kill the server when will be many users...

Comment: On Django how can I handle this? How can I find out that it's been more than a second since a request has been sent.

Answer (score 0):

The `unload` event is not recommended to detect users leaving the page. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/unload_event#usage_notes):

> Developers should avoid using the unload event ... Especially on mobile, the unload event is not reliably fired.

Instead, use the [`visibilitychange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event) event on `document` and/or the [`pagehide`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/pagehide_event) event on `window` (see links for details). For example:

```js
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
    if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden') {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'script.php',
            async:false,
            data: {key_leave: "289583002"}
        });
    }
});
```

Better yet, use [`Navigator.sendBeacon`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon), which is specifically designed for the purpose of sending a small amount of analytics data to a server:

```js
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
    if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden') {
         navigator.sendBeacon('script.php', {key_leave: "289583002"});
    }
});
```