# ajax call is not working for the c# method

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

i want to call the unlock method on closing or redirecting other page, so i have used ajax call. but the method unlock is not firing. please let me know what i am doing

```
 [WebMethod]
public void Unlock()
{
    CreateProject_BL _objcreatebl = new CreateProject_BL();
    _objcreatebl.upd_lockedBy(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["project_id"]), "");
}

  function HandleOnclose() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ProjectDetails.aspx/Unlock",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        });
    }
window.onbeforeunload = HandleOnclose;
```

Comment: Just wanted to a check a few things, have you ensured Unlock function is indeed part of ProjectDetails.aspx ? Also, ProjectDetails.aspx is in the same domain as the file where HandleOnClose sits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you passing project_id in your ajax call???
pass project_id in your method

```
 [WebMethod]
public void Unlock(string project_id)
{
    CreateProject_BL _objcreatebl = new CreateProject_BL();
    _objcreatebl.upd_lockedBy(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["project_id"]), "");
}
```

and then rewrite ajax call as

```
function HandleOnclose() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ProjectDetails.aspx/Unlock",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data : "{project_id:'1234'}",
            dataType: "json"
        });
    }
window.onbeforeunload = HandleOnclose;
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of issues. Firstly your WebMethod expects a querystring parameter, yet you're sending a POST request and you also don't send any data in the request. You should provide `project_id` as a parameter in an object to the `data` property of the AJAX request.

Also note that sending an AJAX request in the `onbeforeunload` event is one of the very few legitimate cases where you need to use `async: false` to stop the page from being closed before the AJAX request completes. Try this:

```
[WebMethod]
public void Unlock(string projectId)
{
    CreateProject_BL _objcreatebl = new CreateProject_BL();        
    _objcreatebl.upd_lockedBy(Convert.ToInt32(projectId), "");
}
```

```js
function HandleOnclose() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false, // only due to running the code in onbeforeunload. Never us it otherwise!
        url: "ProjectDetails.aspx/Unlock",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { projectId: '1234' }
    });
}
window.onbeforeunload = HandleOnclose;
```

Also note that depending on the browser you may be restricted from sending an AJAX request in the `onbeforeunload` event at all. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945932/window-onbeforeunload-ajax-request-problem-with-chrome) for more details.