# `onbeforeunload` function does not detect when I accidentally close browser; when I use ajax

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

I am using javascript function window detector `onbeforeunload` but it does not detect event when I click browser "close X" button. Is it problem in my code or it is its default behavior?

```
    $(window).on('unload onbeforeunload close', function (e) {
  e = e || window.event;

if (e) {

  if(localStorage.openpages==""||localStorage.openpages==null){
    var params = {
    isonline:0
  }
   $.ajax({
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: '<?= base_url()?>UserProfile/setonlinestatus',
    data: params,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    dataType: "json",
    timeout: 60000,
    success: function (response) {
        alert("")
    },
    error: function (jq, status, message) {
        var e = message;
    }
  });}
}});
//navigator.onLine it check whethe ri am online or not
```

Comment: Please have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945932/window-onbeforeunload-ajax-request-in-chrome - it should help you fix your issue

Comment: Detecting the closing of a browser is notoriously difficult. For example you won't get them if the browser crashes. You could use a keep alive mechanism whereby it keeps sending messages to you every minute. Then you'll know roughly how long the user has been online. They're offline if they've not updating within a few minutes.

Comment: It work Ok when I close tab one by one

Comment: @eithed he actually does have async=false

Comment: You may want to use websockets

Comment: The last time I've had to deal with sending data on page close I've actually had to do it with async: true, but I think this has been changed by now. The answer I linked uses `navigator.sendBeacon()` which you can try out, as, looking at the docs, it should do what you want.

Comment: eithed  Thank You so much `navigator.sendBeacon()` solve my issue

Comment: @Artier - no worries. I'd appreciate if you could answer your own question (or I can write up an official answer), in case somebody else stumbles upon this question and doesn't want to waddle through comments. Thanks!

Comment: @eithed Just convert ajax request to navigator sendbeaon() .. It also detect browser Close event

Comment: @Artier I meant - post an answer so the question doesn't stay open

Answer (score 0):

(unload and onbeforeunload) does not completed ajax request and browser close . we need to send same request through navigator.sendBeacon() method,This is used to asynchronously transfer a small amount of data over HTTP to a web server.