# Ajax Synchronous Request Failing in Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax

Have the latest release of Chrome stopped Synchronous Ajax calls? We are getting the error while doing Synchronous Ajax calls. The issue popped up after we updated to latest Chrome version - 73.0.3683.103. Synchronous calls work fine on Firefox and IE for now. We are getting below error

message: "Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'Path...': Synchronous XHR in page dismissal."
name: "NetworkError"

Can someone please suggest a solution to get Ajax Synchronous calls working. I have some functionality where I need to for sure rely on Synchronous call.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, in Chrome they just recently disallowed synchronous ajax during end-of-page events (like `beforeunload` and `unload`). You simply can't do that anymore in Chrome. **Update:** You can again, in v73 and v74, but it's slated (for now) to go away again in <s>v75</s> v80 (Feb 2020). Follow the fun in [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=952452) *(thank you [patmortech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19090/patmortech) for finding that issue)*.

The modern alternative is to use [`sendBeacon`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API/Using_the_Beacon_API), which lets the browser navigate away from the page while still giving you a chance to tell the server that's what's happening. This doesn't hold up page dismissal. But it's only POST, and since it doesn't hold up page dismissal, use cases relying on holding up page dismissal won't work with it.

Comment: Now if only I could find the source I had for that... It's a *very* recent development. Oddly, not listed in removals and deprecations in [v73](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/02/chrome-73-deps-rems) or [v74](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/03/chrome-74-deps-rems). I thought it was something coming in v75 or v76, not something you'd be running into in v73.

Comment: We are seeing the issue in v73 as well...unfortunately nothing is mentioned in release notes of Chrome for this version.

Comment: As you pointed out right, we are calling it in beforeunload and unload.

Comment: @CourageousHeart - I definitely saw this on my Twitter feed within the past 3-4 weeks. It was a bit indirect, they were reporting how much better navigation times were as a result or something like that. Sorry I can't find my source. Note that synchronous ajax is going to be going away entirely at some point.

Comment: could check for [`navigator.sendBeacon`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API/Using_the_Beacon_API) and use that API if browser supports it

Comment: @charlietfl - **Yes!** That's what it was, someone commented on the tweet I can't find saying "the future is beacons." Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: Do we have any quick solution rather than rewriting all the existing code? As our live sites are impacting, some quick solution will really be helpful.

Comment: @CourageousHeart - Find the synchronous ajax and use beacons instead if they're supported by the browser (they are in Chrome). I don't think it's going to get quicker than that.

Comment: does sendBeacon only support POST? I have a use-case for DELETE

Comment: @DragonMoon - Yes, they're always POST. https://w3c.github.io/beacon/#sec-processing-model

Comment: sendBeacon works but it is not immediate, so you can't rely on the sendBeacon request being handled by your server before the next page request. This means you can't unlock a resource on page unload, to acquire the lock again on page load, in the case where the user refreshes the page. Also, use FormData to pass fields for the sendBeacon data param.

Comment: Here's [a Chromium issue related to this change](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=952452). Because of the backlash, they rolled it back in 73/74 again through a route that didn't require a new browser update by the user. They say it will come back with 75, but that may change due to the pushback.

Comment: Despite the pushback, this is being rolled out in Chrome 80 which is due to release February 2020.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks both of you - Crowder and Charlietfl. Using Beacon solved the issue.

In case someone is looking for a solution, can follow this - http://qnimate.com/sending-data-to-server-on-page-unload/

Answer (score 0):

Beacon works alright in some cases, but I'm finding that it's very limited to what you can do and customize (not being able to set a header broke my use case). Another option is to use `fetch` and the `keepalive` flag set to true. According to [this](https://javascript.info/fetch-api#keepalive) link:

> The keepalive option indicates that the request may “outlive” the
>   webpage that initiated it.

```
window.onunload = function() {
  fetch('/analytics', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: "statistics",
    keepalive: true
  });
};
```

It's async, but so is send beacon. I'm just annoyed at Google for forcing this change and breaking a lot of use cases where we want to ensure something is finished before loading....

Comment: This didn't work for me, I had to use `sendBeacon`