# Synchronous ajax request in beforeunload event alternative to support Edge chromium

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I have to make a synchronous ajax request in beforeunload event, but it is throwing an error as synchronous ajax request are not supported in chromium browsers during page unload events.

What could be the alternative to make a synchronous ajax request during page unload event cycle.

```
window.on('beforeunload',function(){
    $.ajax({
         url:'@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")',
         async:false,
         data:formData,
         success:function(){
            //Success logic
         },
         error:function(){
           //Failure logic
         }
    });

});
```

> DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load:

> Note: navigator.sendBeacon() is asynchronous by default, but i need to have a synchronous request in page dismissal.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hi @Ambareesh How about the issue?  Is [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69475590/synchronous-ajax-request-in-beforeunload-event-alternative-to-support-edge-chrom/69491116#69491116) helpful to deal with the issue? Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.

Comment: @YuZhou Yes Thank you, since sync requests are not supported anymore i have used fetch with keep alive property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Synchronous `XMLHttpRequest` has been deprecated, you can refer to [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#synchronous_request). Blink has removed support for sync XHR from page dismissal events (`beforeunload` and `unload`) and you simply can't do that anymore in chromium browsers.

The modern ways are to use `sendBeacon` and `fetch keepalive` as workarounds. For more information, you can refer to [this tweet](https://twitter.com/yoavweiss/status/1115215554753781762) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55676319/ajax-synchronous-request-failing-in-chrome?source=post_page---------------------------). If you don't use these workarounds, I think there's no other way.