# How can i get the total seconds elapsed on a web page before pressing a refresh button or redirecting to another page?

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, timer

I have used this piece of code for a timer. But I am not able to set up a logic to get the total seconds elapsed on this page before pressing a refresh button or redirecting to another page. I also want to pass the value of total seconds elapsed to my database.

Timer Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<Script Language="JavaScript">
    var startDate = new Date();
    var startTime = startDate.getTime();
    function seconds_elapsed ()
    {
        var date_now = new Date ();
        var time_now = date_now.getTime ();
        var time_diff = time_now - startTime;
        var seconds_elapsed = Math.floor ( time_diff / 1000 );
        document.display.timeElapsed.value = pad ( seconds_elapsed );
        setTimeout( "seconds_elapsed ()", 1000 );
        return ( seconds_elapsed ); 
    }
    function pad ( num )
    {
        return ( ( num > 9 ) ? num : "0" + num );
    }
</Script>
</head>
<body onLoad="seconds_elapsed()">

<form method="get" name="display" action="timer.php">
<input name="timeElapsed" type="text" size=8>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want store in a db the seconds elapsed?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini yes

Comment: But in same page like AJAX or in next page?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini actually i am making a recommendation page for some arts. So i want to calculate each users viewing time of an art and add up all the times spent by multiple users on viewing an art. That's why i need to store the seconds in a db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like that :

Second in the page:

```
   <html>
    <head>
    <Script Language="JavaScript">
      var startTime, endTime;

function start() {
  startTime = new Date();
};

function end() {
  endTime = new Date();
  var timeDiff = endTime - startTime; //in ms
  // strip the ms
  timeDiff /= 1000;

  // get seconds 
  var seconds = Math.round(timeDiff);
  window.location="https://website.com/storetimer.php?second="+seconds;
}
    </Script>
    </head>
    <body onLoad="start()">

    <button onclick="end()">Click me</button>

    </body>
```

Now in new page store with insert in your db the variable second like:

```
$second=$_GET['second'];
//insert code
```

Comment: can i work this piece of code for various sessions?

Comment: just use $_SESSION['ID'] if user is logged for store it associated with user.

Comment: if i reload this page, can i still have the elapsed seconds before clicking refresh  button on the php page without pressing a button like click me?

Comment: if you want have always the timer and set "finish" when user log off just set $_SESSION['time'] when he change page and when he logout store it on db

Comment: thanks. You have solved my main issue. Just thinking how can i even get the times when the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Here a small example made with `window.performance.now()`

```
 <body onload="startTimer()">
   <button onclick="showElapsedTime()">Show Seconds</button>
 </body>

<script>
var start;
var end;
function startTimer() {
  start = window.performance.now();
  console.log(start);
}

function showElapsedTime() {
  end = window.performance.now();
  var seconds = (end - start) / 1000;
  alert("Time elapsed: " + seconds.toFixed(2) + " seconds");
}
</script>
```

Comment: it is not giving any alert box answers

Comment: sorry,my mistake. How can i view the calculated value on another page or send it to db?

Comment: and also will it work for different different sessions?

Comment: this timer works only for this page, after reloading the timer is set to 0 again. if you want to send data to your database you could do it with ajax for example or you create an form and send this to your API endpoint

Comment: @Ifaruki that is true but if he store with GET how i explaine the variable will have the end second and he will store it success.

Answer (score 0):

Send an AJAX ping every second, or every time you want.

Or use onunload / onbeforeunload function and send an ajax when leaving. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945932/window-onbeforeunload-ajax-request-in-chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20322988/8099197)