# How to log the time when a user closes a flask view?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, web-applications

I am developing a flask Application, now the requirement is to log the time when the user closes a specific flask view (or exits a flask URL). Simple example would be suppose a user is working on '/home' and now closes the browser tab or the browser itself. Then how to record the time for this particular event?

Please help

Comment: What have you tried? How critical is this... such as browser crashes, power fail etc?

Comment: @charlietfl I have tried using SocketIO but it slows down the app very much. This is critical from analytics point of view because I want to track the time for which a user opened a URL, used it and then closed the URL.

Comment: Take a look at `navigator.sendBeacon()` API. Google analytics or similar service might be another choice

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you so much, I'll try to implement it and get back to you in case I face any issues. appreciate your quick help!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me with similar use case as ajax calls cannot be made anymore so please use [navigator.sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20322988/10738743