# Django run a function while exiting a view or navigating to a different URL from the current URL

Tags: django

In my django application, when I visit a particular URL ex:`enter_database`, a view function is called that adds database entries. Now when I visit a different URL, I want to clear the database entries.
My question, is it possible to call a method while leaving a view/URL.

Note: I can clear the entries by adding the logic in every other view, which is not the approach I want to do. I am looking for a way to call a method while exiting the current displayed view.

Answer (score 0):

In the end of your view you have to create response object and return it.

So I don't know is a correct Django way or not, but you can create custom reponse class and insert logic inside here

```py
class HttpResponseWithDataClearing(HttpResponse):
    def __init__(self, content=b'', *args, **kwargs):
        
        # Some custom logic here (clear the entries?)
        
        super().__init__(content, *args, **kwargs)
```

After that change view's return statement

```py
return HttpResponse(...)
↓
return HttpResponseWithDataClearing(...)
```

Where you want to add custom logic.

<s>If you want to add logic when already response sent and you moving to another page, that is impossible to do at backend.</s>

You must to set javascript action on page leaving. And do ajax request to data_clear_url

```js
window.onunload = function() {
    do_ajax_request("data_clear_url");
}
```

- **EDIT1: onunload method not working**

I tried to reproduce javascript onunload method and looks like ajax request is not properly working with Chrome in this case. You can check this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945932/window-onbeforeunload-ajax-request-in-chrome)

Comment: thanks for the reply, I will it out and let you know

Comment: @SuryaTej Looks like here is problems with Chrome when using onunload feature + ajax request. Added EDIT1 about it.