# Automatic logout user on Window /Tab Close Event in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor web Assembly that runs on windows and the Web I want to log out the user when the Windows/Tab closes.

Is it possible to do it without JavaScript? if yes how can we do it by using C#?
if not then how can we do it by using JavaScript?

Comment: Make your tokens lifespan short like 5 minutes.

Comment: I kept it 5min, but this is not the issue

Comment: You will never be in control of all disconnects some maybe network for example.

Comment: It seems not. You can check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to know how to call js in blazor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will possible without Javascript as you will likely need to tie into the `window.onbeforeunload`. Your application could include a script that creates a handler for this event and execute some logic to perform your logout routine. There are some caveats here. Your logout routine cannot be async as the browser will likely kill the thread before the async routine completes.

Depending on how you implemented your client side authorization you should just be able to clear a cookie or some other persisted data in the browser that lets the application know the user is logged in. If you need to send a request back to the server you could send an synchronous ajax request using Javascript but this may not be supported by some browser. I do believe that chrome supports it.

This post [window.onbeforeunload ajax request in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945932/window-onbeforeunload-ajax-request-in-chrome) provides some details about how to implement this in Javascript.

Comment: I've not used JavaScript yet. I don't know how to use it in the Blazor, do u how to do it?

Comment: Here is the documentation for JsInterop. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-6.0

You would essentially just need to include a javascript file in your main page wwwroot/index.html for wasm or Pages/_Layout.cshtml for server. This file would then wire up the onbeforeunload mentioned above. The actual implementation is dependent on how your app stores it's credentials.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#location-of-javascript for more details of where to add your js files.