# Send AJAX request on page unload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, onbeforeunload

I'm creating a analytics system where I need to send the page read time in seconds with a jquery ajax call on page unload. But the AJAX call is not working on page unload (it's working on load, click etc).

Browser: Chrome 104 Android

My JavaScript:

```
document.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() {

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",

            url: '', /* Current Page */

            data: {

                report: 120 /* Just Example */

            },

            cache:false,

            async: false

        });

    });
```

Comment: [`async: false` has been deprecated for a long time](/q/11448011/4642212). Consider using the [Beacon API](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API) instead.

Comment: I found a latest blog post with `async : false`, URL https://www.webdevsplanet.com/post/building-custom-web-analytics-tool

Comment: Does this answer your question? [window.onbeforeunload ajax request in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945932/window-onbeforeunload-ajax-request-in-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(window).on('unload', function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '', /* Current Page */
        data: {
            report: 120 /* Just Example */
        },
        cache: false,
        async: false
    });
});
```